# complex numbers on the unit circle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Assume that $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ are three distinct points on the unit circle in the complex plane. Then, $$arg{\frac{z_1}{z_2}}=2arg{\frac{{z_3}-{z_1}}{{z_3}-{z_2}}}.$$ What is the *geometric* interpretation of the above identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angle at the centre (the origin) is twice the angle at the circumference.

Comment: Yes, and for more information, this is the central angle theorem (if I recall correctly).

Comment: @rb612 -- Inscribed angle theorem.